# Click a submit button in the hidden form using jquery?

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery-ui, jquery

I have 25 products showing in a page. Each product contains a form within it.
As I have to drag a product to the mini cart on the right. For this I need the form id of the product to be dragged.

With the help of jquery I am getting the id of the form. Now I want to click the submit button within that form. Is there any way to do this with the help of jquery.

I am using jquery find function , but its not working.

Here is my jquery code :

```
$("#ajaxCartUpdate").droppable({
                accept:'.ui-draggable',
                drop: function( ev, ui ) {
                    var td_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('view-test-attributes')[0].getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('td');                        
                    var form_id = td_obj[td_obj.length-1].getElementsByTagName('form')[0].id;
                    document.getElementById(form_id).action = '';
                    document.getElementById(form_id).find('.ajax-cart-submit-form-button').click();

                }
            });
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="add-to-cart">
  <form class="ajax-cart-submit-form" id="uc-product-add-to-cart-form-2-1" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/js_ajax/">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="edit-qty-3" name="qty">
    <input type="submit" class="form-submit node-add-to-cart ajax-cart-submit-form-button ajax-cart-processed" value="Add to cart" id="edit-submit-2" name="op">
   <input type="hidden" value="form-c75deef67555676e4579cd756840cea6" id="form-c75deef67555676e4579cd756840cea6" name="form_build_id">
   <input type="hidden" value="dece0af3cebbdc2ad735891fc7639321" id="edit-uc-product-add-to-cart-form-2-form-token-1" name="form_token">
   <input type="hidden" value="uc_product_add_to_cart_form_2" id="edit-uc-product-add-to-cart-form-2-1" name="form_id">
   <input type="hidden" value="2" id="edit-product-nid-3" name="product-nid">

 </div>
```

I think this is not a big issue, but somehow I am not able to fix it.
Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: what does your html structure look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
$("#ajaxCartUpdate").droppable({
    accept:'.ui-draggable',
    drop: function( ev, ui ){
        $(ui.draggable).closest('form').attr('action','').children('input[type="submit"]').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all I don't have form-id. I have to find it which product is added to cart as there are many products on the page. If I use submit the page redirected to the cart page, which I dont want. I simply want the input button to be clicked using jquery.

Comment: Your code is working fine if I give the static id. But can you help according to my scenario. I am saving formId in a variable. How to use that variable in your above code.

Comment: Ah my bad `ui.draggable` not `ui`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your drop function (no form ID needed, but still obtainable):

```
drop: function(ev, ui) {
    $('.view-test-attributes:first table:first td:last').attr('action', '').submit();
    //if you still need the form id...
    //var form_id = $('.view-test-attributes:first table:first td:last').attr('action', '').attr('id');
}
```

Comment: Not working. Giving error document.getElementById(form_id).find is not a function in firebug console.

Comment: I have pasted the error in the previous comment. $('#uc-product-add-to-cart-form-2-1').attr('action','').children('input[type="submit"]').click();  This code is working, but I need to place a variable name instead of static form_id

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling .click() simply replace it with .submit() .

Edit:
Now that I understand the Question. Try doing this: in a

```
JAVASCRIPT: 
var productData = 'name='+ $("#idForName").val() + '&qty=' + $("#idForQty").val();  

$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "bin/process.php",  
  data: productData ,  
  success: function(data) {  
    //Whatever you want to do at success  
    });  
  }  
});  
return false;
```

So this will be a POST request and you can process it at the server side just like a form submit.

Secondly you can send response (success/failure depending on how you handle it) from the server side that you can check in the call-back function in ajax call success: function(data){...} shown above.
Hope this helps

Comment: If I use simply jquery submit function the product is added to the cart, but the page refreshes and redirected to the cart page. I didn't want the page to refresh.Thats why I want to use the click function

Answer (score 0):

You could also make those inputs hidden within css:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Any jQuery acting upon those inputs should work regardless of whether it's visible in the frontend or not.